# gg plot doesn't seem to recognise a column in the dataframe?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a comparative graph showing all the .csv files from different sensors. Since the data was collected in a similar time frame,  I have attempted to combine the 8 .csv files using this code:

```
#binding all flow files together
files <- list.files(mainFlnm1,pattern=glob2rx("flow20*.csv"),full.names=TRUE) %>%
  lapply(read_csv) %>% bind_rows(id=NULL)
head(files)

#choosing which columns you'd like to work with
main_pollutants <- select(files,"date (UTC)","NO2 (ppb)","VOC (ppb)","pm 10 (ug/m3)","pm 2.5 (ug/m3)", "pm 1 (ug/m3)")
head(main_pollutants)

#creating a plot for visualization
viz <- ggplot(data=plot1_variables,aes_string(x="date (UTC)",y="pm 2.5(ug/m3)"))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
viz
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = elt) : <text>:1:4: unexpected numeric constant 1: pm 2.5 ^
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use backquotes. Also `aes_string` is deprecated

```
viz <- ggplot(data=plot1_variables,aes(x=`date (UTC)`,y=`pm 2.5(ug/m3)`))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Additional follow up. The same error occurred when I tried to run a data frame containing a large amount of data. This time, ggplot created a plot with 0,0 marked.